# Can the left side of the equation be truncated to the first term?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, finite-differences, numerical-calculus, truncation-error

So, I am deriving a high-order compact finite difference scheme, and got into the equation below:

\begin{multline}
            \delta t^2 \{1 + \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\delta x^2 + \delta y^2 + \delta z^2) + \dfrac{h^4}{360} [(\delta x^4 + \delta y^4 + \delta z^4) - (\delta x^2 \delta y^2 + \delta x^2 \delta z^2 + \delta y^2 \delta z^2)]\} \Psi_{i,j,k}^n = \\
           F(\delta x^2, \delta y^2, \delta z^2) \Psi_{i,j,k}^n + \mathcal{O}(h^6),
\end{multline}

where $\delta x^2$, $\delta y^2$ and $\delta z^2$ are central finite difference operators for the second derivative, $F$ is a function dependent on this operators, $h$ is grid distance to the discrete version of the problem, and $\Psi(x,y,z,t) \rvert_{i,j,k}^n = \Psi_{i,j,k}^n$ is a function dependent on position and time. Can I truncate only the left side of this equation to the first term, i.e., to $\delta t^2 \Psi_{i,j,k}^n$, and keep the right side as it is?

My derivation is just like the ones made in papers "High-Order Compact Finite Difference Methods" and "A High-Order Compact Formulation for the 3D Poisson Equation" by Spotz & Carey.

Comment: I'm somewhat hesitant here, so I'm only going to comment and not give an official answer.  But I would say that if you know (because of accuracy, stability, and similar considerations) that you only need a second-order scheme, then, yes, delete everything on the LHS other than the second-order term.  The remaining terms (again, if you know you need no more than second order) aren't doing any good.

Answer (score 0):

If you truncate the LHS as described, you will end up with an $O(h^2)$ scheme.  If you are OK with that, that's fine, but why are you exploring an HOC scheme?  The $h^2/12$ term on the LHS has readily available finite difference approximations, and if you include that in your overall approximation, you immediately bump up the accuracy to $O(h^4)$.  The downside, perhaps, is that you force yourself into an implicit method, but the upside is that it should be guaranteed to be stable.  The references you cite might also attempt to approximate the $h^4/360$ terms by differentiating the governing equation, but only if 6th-order accuracy is desired.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! An implicit method is exactly what I am avoiding. I want to keep the RHS accurate up to $\mathcal{O}(h^6)$. So, can I make the left side accurate to $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ and keep the right side accurate to $\mathcal{O}(h^6)$?

Comment: You can do it, of course, but I'm not sure why.  Your solution $\Psi$ will be $O(h^2)$.  You could do the numerical experiments and see if there is any benefit: oscillations or stability?  But inferring the governing equation here, I wouldn't expect those to be problems.

Comment: Well, in the equation I have written,

\begin{multline}

F(\delta x^2,\delta y^2,\delta z^2) \Psi_{i,j,k}^n = c^2 (\delta x^2 + \delta y^2 + \delta z^2) \Psi_{i,j,k}^n + \dfrac{c^2 h^2}{6} (\delta x^2 \delta y^2 + \delta x^2 \delta z^2 + \delta y^2 \delta z^2)\Psi_{i,j,k}^n - \dfrac{c^2 h^4}{120} (\delta x^2 \delta y^2 \delta z^2) \Psi_{i,j,k}^n.

\end{multline}

Comment: I am trying to deduce the equation given by Kowalczyk in "Boundary and medium modelling using compact
finite difference schemes in simulations of room
acoustics for audio and architectural design
applications", wich also appears in "A classification of split methods for hyperbolic
equations in several space dimensions" by Gourlay & Mitchell. Kowalczyk simply set some parameters on the left side to zero, so the equation is not implicit, but still has the 27 point stencil to make it more accurate.